# How to link a component from one file to a component in another file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Say I have a component (header.jsx) which has a button. When that button is clicked I want to open a Dialog that I created with Material UI. This dialog component is in another file I called dialog.jsx. I know how I could do it all in one file: simply create a function that is linked to the button and calls a show event on the dialog tag. However if I were to separate these two into components in separate files, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Material UI actually has a great article on this topic, assuming I'm understanding your question correctly. If I misunderstood your question, let me know.

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dialog

Comment: @BrandonLewis They do, however what I am trying to do involves showing the Dialog from a button outside of the Dialog's component file. So basically inside a parent.jsx file I have a button. When that button is pressed, it would essentially call a function inside dialog.jsx that shows the Dialog element. How can I pass that function that shows the dialog into my parent.jsx file

Comment: Earlier, I commented that I didn't know of a way to expose methods on a child component to its parent. That actually wasn't true. I've added an answer below detailing how you can do this. However, I would advise you to read the article from the React docs that I linked in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can user `ReactDom.render` method for rendering a component on a particular action

suppose I have dialog.jsx like

```
var Dialog=React.createClass({
 //render function goes here
});
module.exports=Dialog
```

I want to use this component on button click then your parent component should be like

```
var parent=React.createClass({
click:function()
{
 ReactDom.render(<Dialog />,document.getElementById("child");
},
render:function()
{
 return(
   <div>
    <div id="child">
    <div>
    <button onClick={this.click} />
   </div>
  )
}
});
```

hope this may help you

Comment: This unfortunately does not solve my issue. The Dialog element I am rendering in the Dialog.jsx file is naturally set to hidden. So to show it I need to call a function that changes the state to shown. So when I render the element when the button is clicked, that function that shows the Dialog is still never called. Any idea on how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this....

```
var React = import('react'),
Dialog = require("path.to.dialog.jsx"),

header = React.createClass({
    componentWillReceiveProps: function(){
        this.setState({"showDialog" : false});
    },
    onButtonClick : function(){
        this.setState({"showDialog" : true});
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Your other layout>
                    <Button text="Open dialog" click={this.onButtonClick} />
                </Your other layout>
                <Dialog show={this.state.showDialog} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you're trying to do by passing a `ref` prop to the `Dialog` component. You then can call methods on the `Dialog` component by reference to the `this.refs` object inside the `Parent` component. Here's a CodePen showing this in action. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgNVpa Obviously, the code in CodePen is all in one file. Below is how you would do it in multiple files.

Now, just because you *can* do this doesn't mean you should. I would recommend the approach @HaZardouS took in his answer. That's the classic React pattern. In the React docs, they caution against overuse of `refs`.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

> If you have not programmed several apps with React, your first
>   inclination is usually going to be to try to use refs to "make things
>   happen" in your app. If this is the case, take a moment and think more
>   critically about where state should be owned in the component
>   hierarchy. Often, it becomes clear that the proper place to "own" that
>   state is at a higher level in the hierarchy. Placing the state there
>   often eliminates any desire to use refs to "make things happen" –
>   instead, the data flow will usually accomplish your goal.

**Dialog.jsx**

```
class Dialog extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      open: false
    };
    this.open = this.open.bind(this);
    this.close = this.close.bind(this);
  }

  open() {
    this.setState({
      open: true
    });
  }

  close() {
    this.setState({
      open: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.open) return <p>Dialog is open.</p>;
    else return <p>Dialog is closed.</p>
  }
}

export default Dialog;
```

**Parent.jsx**

```
import Dialog from './Dialog';

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.openDialog = this.openDialog.bind(this);
    this.closeDialog = this.closeDialog.bind(this);
  }

  openDialog() {
    this.refs.dialog.open();
  }

  closeDialog() {
    this.refs.dialog.close();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.openDialog}>Open Dialog</button>
        <button onClick={this.closeDialog}>Close Dialog</button>
        <Dialog ref="dialog" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

React.render(<Parent />, document.querySelector('#react-app'));
```